# Have require.js load my files only when I actually need them

Tags: requirejs

I know this is the whole point of require.js, but it does not behave this way in my situation.

I am creating a single page Backbone.js application. The main entry point to the application is trough a router. Let's say I have 3 routes:

```
users: function(){
    require('users');
},
products: function(){
    require('products');
},
groups: function(){
    require('groups');
},
```

Based on the function I call I want to load the file, but require.js does not do this.

Instead it downloads all the files for my complete website everywhere there is a require. I haven't even called the function but it loads the file.

Is there a way to have require.js behave as it should, and download the file only when I am actually inside the function.

Comment: Why did you delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490131/strange-variable-undefined-error-in-javascript ?

Comment: Sorry but i thought the question was too vague. I had to post the code before it would make any sense. And I figured out what the problem was. As you can see from this question I use require.js. Now the problem was that require.js did not actually load the files before I called the function, but the values were there in the debugger. I edited in some hard dependencies and everything is ok now.

Comment: Was it wrong for me to delete it?

Comment: so was I right that `console.log` just show you wrong data, while debugger shows correct? If so - probably it's worth having such question here because it is common

Comment: Added the question and solution again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493926/strange-variable-undefined-error-in-console-log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can basically do what you have in your code snippet. It'd look something like this:

```
users: function(){
    require(['users'], function(Users){
        //Code
    });
},
products: function(){
    require(['products'], function(Products){
        //Code
    });
},
groups: function(){
    require(['groups'], function(Groups){
        //Code
    });
},
```